# The result of opening multiple panes in Windows Terminal via ps1 script is unpredictable

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

I made a pretty simple PowerShell script to run my project.

```
$path = './Desktop/Code/projects'
$windowId = 'app'
$wtCommand = 'split-pane'

$command = "wt -M -w $windowId pwsh -NoExit -c 'cd $path/app/client && npm run dev' && " +
           "wt -M -w $windowId $wtCommand -V pwsh -NoExit -c 'cd $path/app/backend && air' && " +
           "wt -M -w $windowId $wtCommand -V pwsh -NoExit -c 'cd $path/app/admin && npm run dev' && " +
           "wt -M -w $windowId $wtCommand -H pwsh -NoExit -c 'cd $path/Auth/server && air' && " +
           "wt -M -w $windowId $wtCommand -V pwsh -NoExit -c 'cd $path/service_1 && air' && " +
           "wt -M -w $windowId $wtCommand -V pwsh -NoExit -c 'cd $path/service_2 && docker run -p 8090:8090 service_2:latest'"

Invoke-Expression $command
```

And it ALWAYS opens exactly two tabs, but sometimes it opens all the panes correctly, sometimes don't split the editor at all, running just random two apps. Really random behavior.

But if I change command to the `new-tab` instead of the `split-pane`, it will open all the 6 tabs every time just fine.

The terminal version is 1.19.10302.0. I've tried pre-release too, same there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that launching multiple `wt.exe` instances, as you've tried - each of which launches *asynchronously* - can lead to race conditions.

You can avoid the problem - while also speeding up the operation - if you use a *single* `wt.exe` call and pass it all subcommands *at once*, separated with `;`:

```bash
$path = './Desktop/Code/projects'
$windowId = 'app'
$wtCommand = 'split-pane'

wt -M -w $windowId pwsh -NoExit -c "cd $path/app/client && npm run dev" `; `
         $wtCommand -V pwsh -NoExit -c "cd $path/app/backend && air" `; `
         $wtCommand -V pwsh -NoExit -c "cd $path/app/admin && npm run dev" `; `
         $wtCommand -H pwsh -NoExit -c "cd $path/Auth/server && air" `; `
         $wtCommand -V pwsh -NoExit -c "cd $path/service_1 && air" `; `
         $wtCommand -V pwsh -NoExit -c "cd $path/service_2 && docker run -p 8090:8090 service_2:latest"
```

Note:

- Because `;` is a metacharacter in PowerShell (statement separator), it is escaped as `` `; ``
- For readability, the `wt.exe` call is broken into multiple lines, which requires a line-ending `` ` `` for line-continuation (note that it must be the *very last character* on each interior line).
- Direct invocation of `wt.exe` is used in lieu of your [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) approach:

  - [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); except in unusual circumstances, [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script / command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).
  - Direct invocation necessitated switching the individual `-c` arguments to [expandable (interpolating), double-quoted string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) strings to ensure interpolation of the `$path` references.