# Running PS script remotely as admin with no user prompts?

Tags: powershell, silent

I've got some CMD commands that I need to run in PowerShell as an admin or using my admin account, with no user prompts.

I need to run them in PowerShell because the platform I'm using (defender for endpoint) to deploy the script to the user PC only accepts PowerShell, but the commands are command prompt commands.

The script is to fix a windows activation issue.
So far what i have is below, however there is a confirmation box that pops up after every command asking to click OK that i need to get rid of, i also need a way of making it run as admin via the script itself as im not sure that the platform deploying the script will do so.

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "cmd.exe /c slmgr /upk"
Start-Sleep 3
Invoke-Expression -Command "cmd.exe /c slmgr /cpky"
Start-Sleep 3
Invoke-Expression -Command "cmd.exe /c slmgr /rearm"
```

I tried adding the following at the top but it hangs:

```
powershell.exe -NonInteractive
```

I also tried:

```
powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ea 0
```

this no longer hangs but the prompts still display

Is there a way of running this remotely without defender for endpoint as an intermediary?

Comment: You are working of off invalid knowledge/assumptions. slmgr is a vbscript, it's not dependent on CMD. Plus you need to figure out how to make the commands not give output at all first, then you can move on to deploying it through tools.

Comment: As an aside: [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); except in unusual circumstances, [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script / command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).

Comment: The `slmgr.vbs` commands you're trying to invoke require _elevation_ (running as administrator). From _non-elevated_ sessions, you'll invariably get prompts. To avoid them, makes sure you call from an already-elevated session.

Comment: @mklement0 i get prompts when running as administrator locally as well but thanks guys.

Comment: Add pipe to PS commands the following to suppress output : | out-null

Comment: Why such complexity if slmgr has keys to [run on a remote computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/activation-slmgr-vbs-options#using-slmgr-on-remote-computers)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the only / true cause of your problem, but it definitely is a potential one:

**tl;dr**

Assuming that you're already running with elevation, try:

```bash
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

# Get the full file path of slmgr.vbs via $env:PATH
$slmgrFullPath = (Get-Command slmgr.vbs).Path

# Use cscript.exe to execute it as a console application:
cscript $slmgrFullPath /upk
Start-Sleep 3
cscript $slmgrFullPath /cpky
Start-Sleep 3
cscript $slmgrFullPath /rearm
```

See below for a simpler alternative, which, however, involves changing the default WSH host.

---

##### Background information:

`slmgr`'s full file name is [`slmgr.vbs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/activation-slmgr-vbs-options), i.e. it is a VBScript to be executed by WSH, the Windows Scripting Host, of which there are two:

- `cscript.exe` is for running scripts as *console* applications,
- `wscript.exe` is for *GUI* applications.

When you invoke a `.vbs` file *directly*, it is the *default* host that matters, which is `wscript.exe` by default.

If a script that was designed to be invoked with `cscript.exe` is invoked with `wscript.exe` instead, each of its `WScript.Echo` calls turns into a *GUI message box* instead of printing to the console. This is what seems to be happening in your case.

If you don't want to rely on the default, use either `cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe` *explicitly*, as needed, but you must then specify the file *path* of the `.vbs` file as an argument - just the file name - even though it is discoverable via `$env:PATH` in the case of `slmgr.vbs` - is then not enough.

This is the approach demonstrated above, which uses [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) to determine `slgmr.vbs`' full path and passes that to `cscript.exe`.

However, there is an alternative:
If acceptable, you can change the default:
`cscript //H:CScript` makes `cscript.exe` the default host, so that invoking `slmgr` (or `slmgr.vbs`) *alone* is then enough.
Note that changing the default host itself requires *elevation* (running as administrator) too.

Applied to your case:

```bash
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

# Make cscript.exe the default WSH host.
cscript //H:CScript

# Now you can call `slmgr` directly, and it will act
# like a console application
# Use cscript.exe to execute it as a console application:
slmgr /upk
Start-Sleep 3
slmgr /cpky
Start-Sleep 3
slmgr /rearm
```