# when i output to a variable appear problem?

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, psql

when i exec command in powershell:

```
psql --command "\encoding" "host=XXX port=XXX user=XXX password=XXX dbname=postgres"
```

Output:

```
gbk
```

when i exec command in powershell:

```
$a=psql --command "\encoding" "host=XXX port=XXX user=XXX password=XXX dbname=postgres"
Write-Output $a
```

Now the output is different:

```
utf-8
```

this why?

Comment: I think you meen `encoding`, not `enconding`..

Comment: i has been modified，thank you

Comment: Just fix your typo and see the result

Comment: I was very confused to get this result

Comment: Or I want to know the right way to write it

Comment: It looks like [`psql`](https://www.postgresguide.com/utilities/psql/) adjusts its character encoding based on whether its stdout prints directly to the console (terminal) or is connected to a pipe (which is what happens behind the scenes with `$a=...`). Note that if the output is indeed UTF-8 in that case, you need to (temporarily set `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Utf8Encoding]::new()` first - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35980675/45375) (middle section) for details.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question。when i use  "<command> | Tee-Object a.log ", Still get the wrong answer "UTF-8"

Comment: @zuker, that's not surprising, because _piping_ to another command (`Tee-Object`, in this case) equally involves a capturing `psql`'s output via an IPC pipe.

Comment: i try "<command>  >a.log" or "<command> 2>&1 > a.log",get the wrong answer "UTF-8". It seems like I can't write the correct result('gbk') to a variable or file

Comment: @zuker, all of these variations will predictably yield the same result as `$a=...`, because they all involve capturing the program's output via a pipe. What is the meaning of the value? Is it meant to reflect the encoding that the _database_ uses, or the encoding that the `psql` CLI itself uses for its output?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your comments

When I look at the postgres doc

I find notty or tty will lead 'ttl' to different values

I can set 'PG CLIENT ENCODING' to solve the problem