# Powershell - Console output overridden/mixed

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-line, console, command-prompt

Have you ever experienced mixing of console outputs from different commands (different execution order than intended) ?

The text with audio.part was the external call of command line executed in powershell at the end of the script which was merging several parts together.

I've read that sometimes write-host can be executed asynchronously (out of order) in powershell but this feels like some issue with console buffer, cause lines for audio_24038949-24038955 are missing completely, as if they were replaced by that write-host (extra delay, iteration time, etc).

The chunk of console looked like this:

```
...
H:\downloads\temp\audio_24038946.part
H:\downloads\temp\audio_24038947.part
H:\downloads\temp\audio_24038948.part
H:\downloads\temp\audio_24038949.part
extra delay:  8
iteration time:  3989
average:  3990.03400447427
extra delay:  0
iteration time:  3982
average: 3990.03041144902
H:\downloads\temp\audio_24038956.part
H:\downloads\temp\audio_24038957.part
H:\downloads\temp\audio_24038958.part
H:\downloads\temp\audio_24038959.part
...
```

When I copied the output into notepad++ it looked like this:

```
...
H:\downloads\temp\audio_24038946.part
H:\downloads\temp\audio_24038947.part
H:\downloads\temp\audio_24038948.part
H:\downloads\temp\audio_24038949.part
extra delay:  8                                                                                                         iteration time:  3989                                                                                                   average:  3990.03400447427                                                                                              extra delay:  0                                                                                                         iteration time:  3982                                                                                                   average:  3990.03041144902                                                                                              H:\downloads\temp\audio_24038956.part        
H:\downloads\temp\audio_24038957.part
H:\downloads\temp\audio_24038958.part
H:\downloads\temp\audio_24038959.part
...
```

At the start of the script is the $ProgressPreference change:
`$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'`

The following command is inside the loop (the one which hijacked the cmd copy /b below):

```
for ($i = $startSegment; $i -lt $endSegment; $i++) {
    ...
    write-host "extra delay: " $extraDelay`n"iteration time: " $($timer.ElapsedMilliseconds)`n"average: " $($totalTime/$segmentCount)
}
```

Those lines (in-between the binary copy console output) are from 2 iterations of loop. (it was 2249 iterations)
After this loop there's 2 additional (different) write-host commands and 2 write-output to file.

Before external call I changed the $ProgressPreference:
`$ProgressPreference = 'Continue'`

The external calls for binary copy command and looks like this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "cmd" -ArgumentList "/c copy /b `"$($temp)\video*`" `"$($DownloadDirectory)\$($mergedName)_vf.mp4`" " -wait -NoNewWindow
Start-Process -FilePath "cmd" -ArgumentList "/c copy /b `"$($temp)\audio*`" `"$($DownloadDirectory)\$($mergedName)_af.mp4`" " -wait -NoNewWindow
```

The binary copy command generated around 2249 lines of output x2 (same amount of files) and that part of output mentioned above is the only place where it happened.
Each path/file line had 65 characters (trimmed it above for better readability).

I wonder if it's just the console output error or if it interacted in some other way as well.
The binary copy copied/merged all files (including files which were missing in console output) so it should be ok but it still looks strange.

Edit:

That's how it looks like:

```
...
for ($i = $startSegment; $i -lt $endSegment; $i++) {
    ...
    write-host "extra delay: " $extraDelay`n"iteration time: " $($timer.ElapsedMilliseconds)`n"average: " $($totalTime/$segmentCount)
}
write-host end time: $(get-date)
write-host end segment: $($endSegment)
echo "end time: $(get-date)" | Out-File $logFile -append
echo "end segment: $($endSegment)" | Out-File $logFile -append
Start-Process -FilePath "cmd" -ArgumentList "/c copy /b `"$($temp)\video*`" `"$($DownloadDirectory)\$($mergedName)_vf.mp4`" " -wait -NoNewWindow
Start-Process -FilePath "cmd" -ArgumentList "/c copy /b `"$($temp)\audio*`" `"$($DownloadDirectory)\$($mergedName)_af.mp4`" " -wait -NoNewWindow
...
```

Comment: `write-host` and `copy /b` are both writing to the console at the same time in your loop, causing their outputs to overlap. Capture the output of each command into a variable, and then write the output to the console or a file after all commands have finished executing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097354/how-do-i-capture-the-output-into-a-variable-from-an-external-process-in-powershe